# SockJS + Proxy + Apache2 : wss:// not working, only polling

Tags: websocket, proxy, apache2, reverse-proxy, sockjs

I got the following setup:

1. Frontend with SockJS
2. Gateway Server, redirects Socket-Requests to SockJS node server and everything else to a loadbalancer

Websockets are working, but only with polling.
I get the following error in my browser when trying to connect to the sockJS server:

`websocket.js:6 WebSocket connection to 'wss://mypage.com/... failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500`. SockJS server is not logging any error.

I can see in devtools that there is an `https://mypage.com/socket/225/ye1ifrre/xhr_streaming?...` HTTP poll open, but wss:// seems not to work.

This is my gateway apache2 VHOST (I replaced some contents with `...`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # redirect all to HTTPS
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # WebApp VHOST

    ServerName mypage.com

    # Set HSTS
    LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"


    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCipherSuite ...
    SSLCertificateFile /...
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /...
    SSLCACertificateFile /...

    SetEnvIf Referer mypage.com localreferer
    <Location /api>
       Order deny,allow
             Allow from all
    </Location>
    # Proxy All to Application Server Load Balancer except websocket
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # Websocket Proxy Bypass
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* ws://10.2.0.7:9000%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
    ProxyPass /socket http://10.2.0.7:9000/socket
    ProxyPassReverse /socket http://10.2.0.7:9000/socket

    ProxyRequests off

    ProxyPass / http://10.2.0.10:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.2.0.10:80/

    # Set response headers
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "..."
        Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
    Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

</VirtualHost>
```

On my sockJS server I am listening on `10.2.0.7:9000`. On our testing environment where the sockJS server runs on the same VM as the gateway, it works. There I am proxying websockets requests to `127.0.0.1:9000` and sockJS server also listens on `127.0.0.1:9000`.

I am using SockJS Client `1.4.0` and SockJS node server `0.3.20`.

What am I missing here? Could there be an issue with my CSP Headers? I think then I should receive a related error from Chrome.

I read that it might be an issue with sockJS not listening on `127.0.0.1`, or that the socket-request from the client has to be done to the IP address instead of the domain. Anyone else has / had the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into my apache error logs I saw the message `No protocol handler was valid for the URL /socket/316/i0hkgyrq/websocket. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.`.

Turns out I had to enable the proxy webtunnel mod by running the command `sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel`. Everything working now and I see the websocket connection in devtools under the `WS`-Tab